# Count million users from DB realtime?

Tags: sql

What's an efficient way to select count(*) from DB in order to count registered users and create a counter realtime (or almost realtime)? I dont want to run that query every second (on mln users)..was thinking about running each hour and then calculate new users and create an estimated counter..  Things like tracking visitors won't work, bc they come from lots of sites, have to use that users database.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What DB? Both SQL Server and Oracle for instance can maintain the count for you in an indexed (materialized) view. Eg on SQL Server:

```
create view Metric
with schema binding
as
select count_big(*) as RegisteredUserCount 
from dbo.users
where ...;

create clustered index cdxMetric on Metric(RegisteredUserCount);
```

The engine will maintain this count accurate for you, see [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2008 Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
select RegisteredUserCount 
from dbo.Metric with (NOEXPAND);
```

Furthermore, you can cache this result and get automatic invalidation, see [LinqToCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/).

If you are on a MySQL backed system, then probably the best way is to count it once, keep the count in memcached and update it when you register a new user.

Comment: Would it not be the case that the db has to re-evaluate the count each time a new row is inserted? Btw, I don't think a clustered index is needed here. The view will only return one row.

Comment: No, the engine would not have to re-evaluate the entire table (coutn all rows again) every insert/delete. It is smart enough to only update based on the difference (+1 at insert, -1 at delete). Not all aggregate operators support this, but COUNT_BIG does. the clustered index is absolutely required, is what materializes the index. the paper linked in my response covers this topic at length.

Comment: Couple of items. `Schemabinding` is one word. SS tells me that the index must be unique.

Comment: +1 for the info on Count_Big and Noexpand hint. I don't know that the link mentions specifically that Count_Big operates the way you mentioned but running a test verifies that indeed it only updates the metric row and does not rescan the table.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is something that will be executed often, I would recommend keeping a table of metrics which are updated as users are added.

```
Create Table Metric
    (
    RegisteredUserCount int not null Default ( 0 )
    , ...
    )
```

You could then create a series of triggers on the Users table that updates the Metric table or incorporate that into the stored procedure or code used to insert/update/delete Users. Every so often, you could do a verification check on the numbers in the Metric table with the actual number of registered users.

Comment: Metrics table is perfect solution, but possibly safer doing a Select COUNT(*) once every N minutes rather than trigger.

Comment: @Mark B - It depends on how often you are calling Count(*). If you are calling it every 10-20 seconds, you are imposing an awful lot of share locks on your db.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just want to assign the user id to next user. In that case won't a auto incrementing int/bigint fit the bill?

Comment: auto increment won't work, because I am using conditions in the select query and Ids wont match the number

Answer (score 0):

You could count the users once and then create stored procedures that subtract from the user count when members are removed and add to the number when members are added.  I would also create a chron job to run at a schedule you are comfortable with to recount the users table and update your counter.